# How to create a folder using PHP and google Drive API, and immediately change sharing permissions?

Tags: php, google-drive-api

I've successfully been able to create a folder, but I want to figure out how to share it. To use the `permission.create` function I need the `File ID` but I have no idea where to find that.

So basically can I create the folder and immediately set sharing permissions, or do I need the file ID? If so, how do I get that? (this probably applies to any sort of file not just a folder)

This is the code I have to create the folder. I have omitted the code to create the google client object and do the authentication as I thought it was irrelevant.

```
    $drive = new Google_Service_Drive($client);

    $fileA = new Google_Service_Drive_DriveFile();
    $fileA->setName($Title);
    $fileA->setMimeType('application/vnd.google-apps.folder');


    $folder = $drive->files->create($fileA);
```

Comment: https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/create says the "create" method returns a Files resource (i.e. an object representing the new file). If you look at the definition of the Files resource (https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files#resource) you'll see it has a property called "id". So I'd expect that the variable you've rather strangely named as "$folder" will have an "id" property which you can use.

Comment: Wow ok thanks. How exaclty would i get the Id property?

Comment: Like I said, it's a property of the `$folder` object. So in PHP, you get a property like this normally: `$folder->id`. So you could maybe write `echo $folder->id;` on the next line, just to test it. Or you could write `var_dump($folder);` if you wanted to see all the properties of the object, and check what's there.

Comment: I'd like to go ahead and express my most sincere gratitude. It works. I've been stuck for hours and now thanks to you no longer. Very very much appreciated, have a good day!

Comment: No problem. I wrote it up as a proper Answer below, if you would be kind enough to mark it as accepted, thanks. P.S. The documentation is always your friend!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/create says the "create" method returns a Files resource (i.e. an object representing the new file).

If you look at the definition of the Files resource (https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files#resource) you'll see it has a property called "id".

So I'd expect that the variable named as `$folder` will have an `id` property which you can use.

in PHP, you get a property like this normally: `$folder->id`. So you could maybe write `echo $folder->id;` on the next line, just to test it. Or you could write `var_dump($folder);` if you wanted to see all the properties of the object, and check what's there.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to make two calls.  When you create the file / folder the owner is set to the currently authenticated user once you have done that you get back a file id of the new file / directory you created you can then use that in the call to create additional permissions on the file.

```
// Option paramaters can be set as needed.
 $optParams = array(

  'emailMessage' => '[YourValue]',  // A custom message to include in the notification email.

  'sendNotificationEmail' => '[YourValue]',  // Whether to send a notification email when sharing to users or groups. This defaults to true for users and groups, and is not allowed for other requests. It must not be disabled for ownership transfers.

  'supportsTeamDrives' => '[YourValue]',  // Whether the requesting application supports Team Drives.

  'transferOwnership' => '[YourValue]',  // Whether to transfer ownership to the specified user and downgrade the current owner to a writer. This parameter is required as an acknowledgement of the side effect.
  'fields' => '*'
);
// Single Request.
$results = permissionsCreateExample($service, $fileId, $optParams);


/**
* Creates a permission for a file or Team Drive.
* @service Authenticated Drive service.
* @optParams Optional paramaters are not required by a request.
* @fileId The ID of the file or Team Drive.
* @return Permission
*/
function permissionsCreateExample($service, $body, $fileId, $optParams)
{
    try
    {
        // Make the request and return the results.
        return $service->permissions->CreatePermissions($body, $fileId,  $optParams);
    }
    catch (Exception $e)
    {
        print "An error occurred: " . $e->getMessage();
    }
}
```